# amazon s3 bucket returns only "top level" keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am facing a problem that AWSSDKs ListObjects only returns keys of "top level folders" (I know there are no such things like folders in a bucket).
In my bucket I store images in different resolutions. The "folder structure" in the bucket looks like:

year/month/resolution/file in this resolution
(of the image when its uploaded)

If an original image should be updated, all images in smaller resolutions should be deleted. Therefore I want to get all occurences of an image in the bucket. I use the following code snippet to do this and for top level keys it works fine.

```
using (IAmazonS3 amazonS3Client =     Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
{
    ListObjectsRequest S3ListObjectRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();
    S3ListObjectRequest.BucketName = "my_bucket";
    S3ListObjectRequest.Delimiter = "LL.jpg";

    ListObjectsResponse listObjectRequest = amazonS3Client.ListObjects(S3ListObjectRequest);

    foreach (string S3BucketDir in listObjectRequest.CommonPrefixes)
    {
        //delete image
    }
}
```

for LL.jpg i get the following CommonPrefixes:

```
 - 2014/07/T120x120/LL.jpg
 - 2014/07/T160x160/LL.jpg
 - 2014/07/T320x320/LL.jpg
 - 2014/07/T640x640/LL.jpg
 - 2014/07/T76x76/LL.jpg
 - 2014/07/T80x80/LL.jpg
```

but for orp.jpg I should get:

```
 - 2015/05/T120x120/orp.jpg
 - 2015/05/T160x160/orp.jpg
 - 2015/05/T640x640/orp.jpg
```

however it is empty every time.

If I set the prefix

```
S3ListObjectRequest.Prefix = "2015/05";
```

the 3 CommonPrefixes are returned. (If I only use '2015' as prefix its also empty, because ListObjects only searches in 2015/01)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (better say workaround) for this problem. However its incredible slow but it solves the problem for now. Still hoping for a better/faster solution.

I create a list of all possible prefixes of my bucket and check with every prefix and the filename as delimiter for occurrences of the image.

```
        using (IAmazonS3 amazonS3Client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
        {
            ListObjectsRequest S3ListObjectRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();
            S3ListObjectRequest.BucketName = "my.bucket";
            S3ListObjectRequest.Delimiter = "/";

            bool doIt = true;
            IList<string> prefixes = new List<string>();
            IList<string> toCheck = new List<string>();

            do
            {
                ListObjectsResponse response = amazonS3Client.ListObjects(S3ListObjectRequest);

                foreach (string prefix in response.CommonPrefixes)
                    toCheck.Add(prefix);

                if (toCheck.Count > 0)
                {
                    prefixes.Add(toCheck[0]);
                    S3ListObjectRequest.Prefix = toCheck[0];
                    toCheck.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                else
                    doIt = false;

            } while (doIt);

            foreach (string key in prefixes)
            {
                S3ListObjectRequest.Prefix = key;
                S3ListObjectRequest.Delimiter = "filename.jpg";
                ListObjectsResponse response = amazonS3Client.ListObjects(S3ListObjectRequest);

                foreach (string image in response.CommonPrefixes)
                {
                    //path of images to delete
                    Console.WriteLine(image);
                }
            }
        }
```